# Can you pass generic delegate without the type parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, generics, delegates

I have three projects

1. MVC Web application
2. Service application which is kind of two layers business/repository
3. Entity framework (all EF configuration lives here)

**MVC** references > service

**Service**  references > EF

I have these three methods currently that do some work.

```
public bool StoreUpload<T>(UploadInformation information) 
   where T : class, IUploadEntity { }

public bool RemoveUpload<T>(UploadInformation information) 
   where T : class, IUploadEntity { }

public bool CommitUpload<T>(UploadInformation information) 
   where T : class, IUploadEntity { }
```

I call these three methods from my controller using these interfaces which delegate to the work methods above:

```
Boolean StoreUpload(UploadInformation information);
Boolean RemoveUpload(UploadInformation information);
Boolean CommitStoredDocuments(UploadInformation information);
```

Based on a condition from UploadTypes enumeration in a switch I call the correct work method. I do this because I don't want my mvc project to have access to the EF database types otherwise I know someone is going to start querying data from all over the application. I use these switch statements for all interfaced methods:

```
public bool StoreUpload(UploadInformation information)
{            
    switch (information.Type)
    {
        case UploadTypes.AutoIncident:
            return RemoveUpload<AutoIncident>(information);
        case UploadTypes.Incident:
            return RemoveUpload<IncidentInjury>(information);
        case UploadTypes.Inspection:
            return RemoveUpload<Inspection>(information);
        case UploadTypes.OtherIncident:
            return RemoveUpload<OtherIncident>(information);
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

public bool RemoveUpload(UploadInformation information) { ... }
public bool CommitStoredUpload(UploadInformation information) { ... }
```

This method might shed a little light on what the types parameters are being used for. I am updating tables in a generic way using EF.

```
private bool CommitStoredDocuments<T>(UploadInformation information) where T : class, IUploadEntity
{
        var uploads = GetStoredUploads(information.UniqueId);
        var entity = db.Set<T>().Include(e => e.Uploads)
             .Single(e => e.UniqueId == information.UniqueId);
        entity.Uploads.AddRange(uploads);
 ... 

}
```

It would be nice to be able to pass the work method which requires a type parameter as a delegate to the switch work method calls.

```
public bool DoSomeWork(delegateMethod, information) {
    switch(information.Type) { 
         case UploadTypes.AutoInciden:
           return delegateMethod<AutoIncident>(information);
         ...
    }
}
```

Can this be done?
Also, I had trouble constructing a good title for this question so please comment if these is a better way to describe the challenge.

Comment: If the `DoSomeWork` method already holds a reference to the correct method (using `delegateMethod`), why the `switch` clause again?

Comment: I am calling from a tier that doesn't have access to those types.

Answer (score 3):

It cannot be done directly due to several reasons.

First of all, as you probably noticed, `delegateMethod<FooBar>(information)` simply does not compile. This is because in your example the `delegateMethod` is a local variable (method parameter actually, but still a variable), and you cannot apply "type arguments" `<FooBar>` to a variable - you can apply them only on an identifier that indicates a (generic) type or a (generic) method.

Second reason is more interesting. When you pass a method as a delegate, the delegate actually catches the whole method signature, including all parameter types.

```
void Blah<T>(UploadInformation information){ ... }

var one = new Action<int>(Blah); // -> Blah<int>
var two = new Action<float>(Blah); // -> Blah<float>
var thr = new Action<andsoon>(Blah); // -> Blah<andsoon>

MagicDoSomeWork(one, ...); // these all
MagicDoSomeWork(two, ...); // delegates are already bound
MagicDoSomeWork(thr, ...); // and remember their concrete T
```

You need to actually specify the type for the `Action` so a proper version of generic method will be picked from a general description called `Blah`. These delegates are bound to concrete versions of the method and will accept only that types. These delegates are 'closed' in terms of their type arguments. Using normal ways, the `MagicDoSomeWork` will simply have no way of altering the `T` which these delegates already have remembered.

That two things are a kind of show stoppers, since by normal code only, you cannot write things like

```
var nope1 = new Action(Blah);  // ctor for Action NEEDS type parameter
```

since Action constructor simply requires a type parameter. And once you pass any, it will lock the Blah type arguments

Also you cannot use open delegates:

```
var nope1 = new Action<>(Blah); // can't use empty <> in this context :(
```

since `new` operator requires a full type to create an object.

However, with a bit of reflection voodoo, it is possible to analyze and build a generic type or a generic method dynamically.

```
// first, build the delegate in a normal way
// and pick anything as the type parameters
// we will later replace them
var delegateWithNoType = new Action<object>(Blah);
// delegate has captured the methodinfo,
// but uses a stub type parameter - it's useless to call it
// but it REMEMBERS the method!

// .... pass the delegate around

// later, elsewhere, determine the type you want to use
Type myRealArgument;
switch(..oversomething..)
{
    default: throw new NotImplemented("Ooops");

    case ...: myRealArgument = typeof(UploadTypes.AutoIncident); break;
    ...
}

// look at the delegate definition
var minfo = delegateWithNoType.Method;
var target = delegateWithNoType.Target; // probably NULL since you cross layers

var gdef = minfo.GetGenericDefinition();
var newinfo = gdef.MakeGenericMethod( myRealArgument );

// now you have a new MethodInfo object that is bound to Blah method
// using the 'real argument' type as first generic parameter
// By using the new methodinfo and original target, you could now build
// an updated delegate object and use it instead the original "untyped" one
// That would be a NEW delegate object. You can't modify the original one.

// ...but since you want to call the method, why don't use the methodinfo

UploadInformation upinfo = ... ;
newinfo.Invoke(target, new object[] { upinfo });
// -> will call Blah<UploadTypes.AutoInciden>(upinfo)
```

***word of warning**: this is a sketch to show you how the `delegate.Method/Target` and `methodinfo` and `getgenericdefinition` and `makegenericmethod` work. I wrote it from memory, never compiled, never ran. It can contain minor typos, overlooked things and invisible rainbow unicorns. I didn't noticed any. Probably because they were invisible.*

Comment: Thank you, this is what I thought. It will work out the code. This seems to be a solution for this challenge. I had this solution on my mind but wanted to know first.

Comment: @jwize: I edited the text slightly to use your typenames in a few places, It should be easier to read. By the way - the title you chose is quite fine. Passing delegates around in such cases is tricky. What I forgot to write is that you actually may don't need the delegate, especially if you end up with `null` targets. Passing 'bare' MethodInfos may be much easier to understand for future mantainers. (contd)

Comment: @jwize: you can still use delegates like Action/Func to capture the methods, then when you are passing them to another layer, you may pick their .Method, then get .GetGenericDefinition and pass **that** to the other layer. You will be passing the open generic method declaration, with no type parameters filled yet. That would be a very clear "don't use me yet" sign for future readers. But well, it would look more complex than just passing Action<object> to the layer below. Functionally the same (unless the .Target is != null), so pick whatever you like more.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
public bool Invoke(EntityType entityType, ActionType action, Object[] arguments)
    {
        var actionType = Enum.GetName(typeof(ActionType), action);
        var type = GetType();
        var method = type.GetMethods().Single(m => m.IsGenericMethod && m.Name == actionType);

        switch (entityType)
        {
            case EntityType.IncidentInjury:
                var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(IncidentInjury));
                return (bool)genericMethod.Invoke(this, arguments);
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

The enum will just be a list of methods that I want to invoke this way and I create a base class for my services so I don't have to pass the instance to the Invoke method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using delegates, consider using an interface (or abstract class). This way, your methods can retain their generic nature.

For example, if you create an interface like:

```
interface IUploadAction
{
    bool Perform<T>(UploadInformation information)
       where T : class, IUploadEntity;
}
```

Note that the `T` is not exposed in the type, it's only on the method. This is the key part.

Now you can implement this for your database methods:

```
class CommitStoredDocuments : IUploadAction
{
    public bool Perform<T>(UploadInformation information)
       where T : class, IUploadEntity
    {
        var uploads = GetStoredUploads(information.UniqueId);
        var entity = db.Set<T>().Include(e => e.Uploads)
             .Single(e => e.UniqueId == information.UniqueId);
        entity.Uploads.AddRange(uploads);

        //...
    }
}
```

Your switching/dispatching method can look like this:

```
public bool DoAction(IUploadAction action, UploadInformation information)
{
    switch (information.Type)
    {
        case UploadTypes.AutoIncident:
            return action.Perform<AutoIncident>(information);
        case UploadTypes.Incident:
            return action.Perform<IncidentInjury>(information);
        case UploadTypes.Inspection:
            return action.Perform<Inspection>(information);
        case UploadTypes.OtherIncident:
            return action.Perform<OtherIncident>(information);
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

And then you can write something like:

```
IUploadAction storeUpload;

public bool StoreUpload(UploadInformation information) => DoAction(storeUpload, information);
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I follow this one? Then I would have to create a new switch for every implementation which is what I am trying to avoid. Also your code needs a closer look.

Comment: @jwize I misunderstood what the problem was, I'll update my answer... does that help at all?

Comment: Yes, that is how I ended up doing it.